# Why can't I see anything?

Tags: c#

Just tried a GUI code and at first I could see text, buttons after first compile. Then I tried to hook up the buttons to the RadioButton, after compiling this all I was able to see was plain white.

The .xaml code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="GUItest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUItest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="855" Width="1628">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.500,0.525" Margin="0,0,0,-6">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="387,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select an option:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,305,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select an option:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" Width="237" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,0.498"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="ABC" Content="ABC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="297,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="DEF" Content="DEF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="488,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <RadioButton x:Name="ABCButton" Content="ABC" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="297,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="DEFButton" Content="DEF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="488,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select an option:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="238" Height="143" RenderTransformOrigin="0.50-53,0.501">
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="-0.1"/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-0.332"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is the .xaml.cs code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GUItest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ABCButton.IsChecked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ABC");
            }
            else if (DEFButton.IsChecked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("DEF");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just made by me to better understand the GUI.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Best not to assume people are being rude here. That type of comment doesn't belong in a question, so I've removed it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

All of your items fall in the first column and your ColumnWidth of the first one is 0*. This means that the width will be 0 (times) x, which results in a width of 0.

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Try to make this * or 2* or something, or place the items in a different column.
Good luck.

Edit:

Placing the items in a different column can be done by:

```
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="387,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select an option:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1"> <!-- Here the 1 means place this grid in the first column of the main grid -->
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,305,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select an option:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" Width="237" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,0.498"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="ABC" Content="ABC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="297,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="DEF" Content="DEF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="488,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
```